# Use chown to set the ownership of all a folder's subfolders and files?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

How can I use the `chown` command to change the ownership of all a folder's subfolders and files?

Comment: `chown -R` should work for you.

Comment: `chown -R your_username:your_group folder`

Comment: Will any of these answers work if the files inside a folder are owned by someone else and only have user read/write permission?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

From `chown --help`:

```
Usage: chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
  or:  chown [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
Change the owner and/or group of each FILE to OWNER and/or GROUP.

[...]

  -R, --recursive        operate on files and directories recursively

[...]
```

So you need to run (probably with `sudo`):

```
chown -R USERNAME:GROUPNAME /PATH/TO/FILE
```

Or, if the group shall be the specified user's primary group (usually same name), you can also omit the `GROUPNAME` and just give the `USERNAME:` with a colon (no space before it!). It will be set implicitly:

```
chown -R USERNAME: /PATH/TO/FILE
```

To only change the user and leave the group as it is, just specify `USERNAME` and no group name and no colon:

```
chown -R USERNAME /PATH/TO/FILE
```

To only change the group and leave the owner user as it is, just specify `:GROUPNAME` with a leading colon:

```
chown -R :GROUPNAME /PATH/TO/FILE
```

Answer (score 26):

My username is timo and I did this to take ownership to all my files and folders on home directory (transferred from another account):

```
~$ sudo chown -R timo /home/timo/*
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
chown -R <username>:<groupname> <folder>
```

This is how I normally do it, and I usually do this one folder at a time. Doesn't take but a few moments to work through each folder.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:
    chown -hR :

This will also change ownership of symlinks instead of just the destination files that the symlinks point to.

Comment: "chown -hR root /u" mean change the owner of /u and subfiles to "root".

Answer (score 1):

```
man chown
chown options user:group files/folders
```

Not sure why other answers did not cover one dot. **:** And **.** are interchangeable, so you can use one dot for instance

```
chown -R user.group files/folders
```

Answer (score 0):

Either get to the terminal display mode as described elsewhere or do a ssh login from another computer. Usually the account is intact and it will be accessible via ssh.

You may also have an account on the same machine without the login loop problem. If you do, then login to that account (assuming it will let you sudo).

Once in, open a terminal and find the directory under which you can see the username directories. i.e. `/home/username1 /home/username2`

Run `ls -l`

if any of the user directories is owned by root change it by running:

```
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username
```

This example is based on an architecture where the user directories are under `/home/`

Run `ls -l` again to confirm the directory is owned by the user.

This was tested on Ubuntu 20.04