# Unable to upload media to WordPress

Tags: apache2, wordpress

When I go to upload a file to my WordPress site, I get the following error:

`Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

I am running WordPress on an Apache 2.2.2 server, on a Linux machine. The wp-content folder has 775 permissions, and I created a `/uploads` folder inside also with 775 permissions. The user and group for both of these folders, and for the entire WordPress file directory, is `www-data`.

I am running WordPress 4.7.3.

If this is noteworthy, upon installation, my `upload_path` variable was not set. I have since set it to `wp-content/uploads` and manually created the `uploads` directory with 775 permissions.

The process of installation was to install using `wget wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz` and install it from there.

Could this have something to do with it?

No solutions found on the net involving changing permissions, or setting php to unsafe mode, have worked.

Cheers!

EDIT:

Might other files and directories not being owned and grouped by www-data have anything to do with this? `ls -l` makes this:

`-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup    418 Sep 24  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup  19935 Jan  2 12:51 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   7433 Jan 11 11:46 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   5447 Sep 27 16:36 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody   nogroup   4096 Mar  6 10:00 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup    364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   1627 Aug 29  2016 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      3045 Mar 22 21:47 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   2853 Dec 16  2015 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 22 23:09 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 18 nobody   nogroup  12288 Mar  6 10:00 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   2422 Nov 20 20:46 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   3301 Oct 24 22:15 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup  33939 Nov 20 20:46 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   8048 Jan 10 23:15 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup  16250 Nov 28 23:39 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup  29896 Oct 18 23:47 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   4513 Oct 14 14:39 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody   nogroup   3065 Aug 31  2016 xmlrpc.php`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the real problem are permissions, and probably you didn't fully change them as needed or the webserver is running it as a different user than you expect.

I would test it out using sudo like this (replace /var/www with the relevant path):

```
sudo -u www-data mkdir -p /var/www/wp-content/uploads/2017/03
```

If that is working, I would check "dmesg" for AppArmor failures though I don't believe that AppArmor is blocking apache2/php by default from memory.

If that is not working, I would use that as a simple test to explore and fix the permissions to work.  You could start by checking all directory levels permissions

```
ls -lad /var/www /var/www/wp-content /var/www/wp-content/uploads /var/www/wp-content/uploads/2017 /var/www/wp-content/uploads/2017/03
```

Comment: Following the `sudo -u www-data mkdir -p /var/www/wp-content/uploads/2017/03` command, I am allowed to make that directory. I am struggling to interpret what the output of `dmesg` means.

Comment: Now, if I go to upload a file, there is an error:

`The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2017/03.`

Comment: I would revert your PHP configuration changes back to default also

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Trent Lloyd! Unfortunately, no amount of expertise can combat tired eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sure do feel like a Dunder-Mifflin.

Checked the running processes by using `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and noticed all processes were running under `http-web`. I confirmed through `ls -l` that my permissions in all of my WordPress folders were for some `www-data` user and group.

I changed all of that using `chown -R http-web:http-web /var/www/html` (I have an extra `html` folder inside of `www`).

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020186/the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-uploads

[Use chown to set the ownership of all a folder's subfolders and files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693418/use-chown-to-set-the-ownership-of-all-a-folders-subfolders-and-files)