# Change Owner ID and Group ID of all files/folders in a folder

Tags: command-line, server, permissions

I am very new to Ubuntu.

But I have a problem with my files/folders in my wordpress VPS (Nginx, Ubuntu).

- I check the permission of file.
- The permission of folders is 755 => That's good.
- The permission of Files is 644 = That's good.
- But the owner ID is 0 => I must change it to 113.
- And Group ID is 0 => I must change it to 117.

I can change one by one. But there are thousands of files and folders.

Is there anyway to do this in batch mode, using terminal, command line or something...???

Please help me!

Image: https://upanhtocdo.com/image/HGhDZ

Comment: You wont be able to do so from windows. You need access to the server and execute the command trietend shows from the directory(!!!!!) you want to do that. So be very careful.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: [Use chown to set the ownership of all a folder's subfolders and files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693418/use-chown-to-set-the-ownership-of-all-a-folders-subfolders-and-files)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SFTP to edit the files. Login with your SFTP credentials to your server over `ssh`

Than you can use the `chown` option `-R`  to handle files and directories recursive.

```
sudo chown -R user:goup folder
```

You can use the names of groups and owner or the UID and GID. I would recommend to use the names in order to avoid typos.

Comment: His image is from windows. So this command might need some explaining; like how to access his system. And "folder" probably needs explaining too. His image shows `/var/www/html/` so might be include in the answer ;)

Comment: He asked for a way, for example with using terminal, so i assumed he is familar with using ssh. But you are right, i'll add this.

Comment: Please explain more detail.

Comment: Tell us something about your skills. Where should i start? Do you know what ssh is and how to use it? Have you ever used the linux terminal in linux?

Comment: .I conect my server via SSH. I want change UID and GID of all files/subfolders of folder /var/www/html/. UID to 113 and GID to 117. Can you show me the code to do that.

Comment: I have terminal windows of server on my desktop app.

Comment: Ok you are on your server via ssh now, right ? So just execute the command i postet. `sudo chown -R 113:117 /var/www/html`. After that you can look for the permissions with `ls -lah /var` for example.

Comment: OMG. That's work. Thank you Pro! Thank you againt! :)

Comment: You're wellcome. I am not a pro. You should read a bit around security if you have a server in the web. And don't show the IP-Adress the next time in the screenshots