# Mount drive by cli working but not by gui

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus

Until yesterday if I wanted to access a shared partition with Windows in my machine I just clicked `other locations` -> *the partition* and could work normally, but now I get

> **Unable to access location**
> Not authorized to perform operation

I tried mounting by terminal with mount to */mnt* and it worked, if I go to `mnt` in nautilus it loads my files.

Any ideas how to restore the functionality to mount just by clicking?

Comment: This happened to me some weeks ago and I found that the permissions were changed from the user to root. Maybe that's why you are able to access it only from the terminal. I would say that you first check the owner of your Windows partition if it is root and then change it to the user using `chown` https://askubuntu.com/questions/693418/use-chown-to-set-the-ownership-of-all-a-folders-subfolders-and-files  , but remember don't change the ownership of the root directory of Ubuntu ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve It, strangely, it was caused by Chrome Remote Desktop as reported here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/693294
After stoping the process and uninstalling it, the problem was gone.