# Ubuntu 20.04. SSD & HD. Permissions good on SSD. Permissions wrong on HD. Want to change permissions HD. UDATA at /dev/sda3 Terminal command?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive, ssd

Inspiron 3891.  Running 20.04.  Gnome version 3.36.8.  Ubuntu on a SSD.  My data drive is 2 TB hard disk located at /dev/sda3/  Partition has several folders.  Folders have some files.  Both the folders and the files show "Me" as the owner and "steve" as group with no write delete authority.  I have no idea where "Me" came from.  But I (steve) am the owner and the superuser on the SSD and all the files and folders.  I want to change the ownership of the folders and files on the hard disk so I can use it for storage.  What terminal command can I use to change ownership of folders and files on the hard disk?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It seems like you are experiencing some problem with your hard drive, but instead of asking about that problem, you are asking about something else that you think might solve the other problem. Can you edit your question with more details? Are you getting errors when you try to use it? If so, copy/paste them.  What file system does the drive use? Why do you think this is happening? Is there so much stuff on it, that you can't relocate files elsewhere so you can format the hard drive?

Comment: FYI, `chmod` is the command to change permissions and `chown` is the command to change ownership. But I would hold off on using these until we can determine what is the actual problem.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the chown command.  But I don't know how to write the appropriate script when the folders and files are on a different drive.  The hard disk is mounted at /media/steve/UDATA.  when I type ls /media/steve/UDATA I see the correct folders.  What would be the correct chown command for this situation.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/q/693418